# Is there a way for me to get Firefox to recognize these smart card non-root certificates?

Tags: firefox, certificate, active-directory

My company uses active directory to manage all of their users, and all access to the internal network as well as the internet requires smart card authentication. With IE and Chrome this works fine, because they both use the system certificate store. I'm trying to use Firefox because its what I'm used to. I enabled the `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` in Firefox but it still didn't work.

After digging around in `certutil` I found that the smart card certificates are non-root certificates (as shown below), which is why Firefox is not identifying and using them for authentication. Is there a way for me to get Firefox to recognize these non-root certificates?

```
...
Subject: CN=Smith, Ramsay (rsmith3), OU=Standard Accounts, DC=NA, DC=Org, DC=com
Non-root Certificate
Template: CLMSmartcardLogon, CLM Smartcard Logon
Cert Hash(sha1): dca0e63cde75197c7f92b2b34b00a5e1f447a146
  Key Container = d84c3849-982f-476e-461673ace7d83774
  Provider = Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider
Private key is NOT exportable
Encryption test passed
...
```

Comment: What isn't clear is the reason, the certificate on the card, isn't being signed by a root certificate.  It should be as simple as trusting certificate authority that signed the certificate on the card.  I assume you have configured Firefox to handle a smart card properly.

Comment: @Ramsay: I don't understand what your note about "non-root certificates" is based on. End-user certificates used for authentication _almost always_ are "non-root", except in the most lazy setups. That has never been a problem, and that has never been a reason for Firefox to avoid using the certificate.

Comment: I may simply have been confused about the terminology. Because they were non-root, and the Firefox option enabled root certificates, I assumed that was the issue.